# Python multiprocessing Listener 0.0.0.0 Windows documentation

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

In the Python 2.7.5 documentation on `multiprocessing.connection.Listener` ([link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing.connection.Listener)), it states that

> **Note** If an address of ‘0.0.0.0’ is used, the address will not be a
>   connectable end point on Windows. If you require a connectable
>   end-point, you should use ‘127.0.0.1’.

What precisely does this mean, in the context of:

- I have tested the `Client` (`conn=Client(('localhost', port))`) and `Listener` (`listener=Listener(('0.0.0.0', port))`)  on the *same machine* and communication works.
- I have tested it with client and listener on different machines (where the listener was created with `0.0.0.0`, and the client was given the IP address of the listener machine) and communication works.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe this is about the `SO_REUSEADDR` issue (see http://bugs.python.org/issue2550 and elsewhere), and was retroactively added to the 2.5-3.2 docs when `Listener` was changed to not use `SO_REUSEADDR` on Windows with 3.3. If I'm right, the truth isn't that it works on localhost but not wildcard; it's that it "usually" works on localhost but only "often" works on wildcard, which means listening on localhost isn't really a fix.

Comment: Thanks, I read through the posted issue. It seems like the `SO_REUSEADDR` is more about how the OS responds to a request to reuse an address (and here there are apparently differences btwn Win and Linux, with Windows exposing `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` as a flag to mandate behaviour.  Do you have an intuition as to what *connectable end point* might mean?

Comment: Also, it looks like that fix made it into 2.7.

Comment: I think the location of that note in the documentation may be misleading. A `Listener` with address `0.0.0.0` seems to work (and listens for connections on all interfaces), but for a `Client` it will not. Perhaps it's in the docs at all only because some other OSs (including, I think, MacOS and Linux) do allow `Client` connections to `0.0.0.0`, as an alternate spelling of "localhost"?

Comment: Compare [3.3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#l561) to [2.7](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#l247) source. Whatever the multiprocessing fix was related to #2550 didn't make it into 2.7.

Comment: @Blckknght: could be (it was also my first thought), but the phrasing *connectable end point* is bothering me, because I can't think that the author would refer to a client in that way.

Comment: Meanwhile, this note was not in [pyProcessing](http://pyprocessing.berlios.de/doc/connection-ref.html) before it joined the stdlib as `multiprocessing`, which implies that there was probably some discussion of it on either the bug tracker or python-dev, so instead of trying to guess, you can search…

Answer (score 2):

According to the discussion for [issue 3270](http://bugs.python.org/issue3270), that text was added to the documentation merely to indicate that the specific address `0.0.0.0` could not be used as a *connectable end-point*, as it might be used from a client.  As such, @Blckknght's comment above was pretty much correct.

The note was added to the documentation [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/8b51d96360b0/).

Comment: Good job in finding the source of the note in the docs. I almost submitted my comment as an answer, but I couldn't find any confirmation that this was the real reason for it. It looks like some tests had previously assumed that `Listener.address` would always be an address you could pass to `Client` to get connected to the Listener. That isn't the case with a `0.0.0.0` IP address on Windows, thus the note about `'0.0.0.0'` not being a "connectible end point" on all platforms.